# Very similar imports - did I add this dependency twice somehow?

Tags: java, android-studio, import, scichart

I'm trying to setup the [Scichart](https://www.scichart.com/) libraries using [this](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/Tutorial%2001%20-%20Adding%20SciChart%20libraries%20as%20dependencies.html) guide.

The library I [downloaded](https://www.scichart.com/downloads/) has a structure that looks like this:

[image]

I copied the 5 `.aar` files and the 4 documentation `.jar` files into the `libs` folder of the app in Android Studio, like so:

[image]

Following a guide I read online (I've never added an external library before) I found that for the documentation to work I'd need to add it as an attachment here:

[image]

However, when I right clicked and went to library properties it looked like it already had it - I assume that since the files are in the `lib` folder in the app they're seen and used.

So, everything should work. The problem is that Android Studio is offering to import one of two classes with the exact same package name but different Gradle packages (? don't know if that's the right term) on the right. Picture:

[image]

Why is it doing this? What did I do wrong when adding the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per tutorial (*Tutorial 01*), the sections

- Using Maven (*well it's more Gradle*)
- Using bare SciChart libs

Are **mutually exclusive**.
If you already referenced their libraries via `build.gradle` (as described in the tutorial, *Using Maven* part), you don't need (and don't have) to put `JAR`(s) inside any folder and then add them to the Module settings, or whatever. Even sources will be pulled down automatically.

What you're doing is creating a local repository, in addition to using the remote one. That's why the duplicated libraries.

Comment: That would do it - thanks. :) Guess I need to pay more attention to section headers.

Comment: @TheKingElessar don't worry. I remember when I started dealing with dependency management using Maven or Gradle. Madness